# Widget data in centreon is not coming due to accidental file deletion

Tags: nagios, centreon

I am on Centreon 2.8.22, I was playing with a certain widget and I accidentally extracted all the files of that widget in the widget folder. So then I was deleting all the files which was extracted here and I think I have accidentally deleted a main configuration file in this folder (not sure which file is that, maybe its require.php or something else.

Now the thing is, how do I get my widget to work because earlier it was working.

[image]

Comment: You could compare the folder with a current backup to see which files are missing. Or you could just restore your backup.

Comment: @digijay - There is no backup.